# Getting all values before a certain date

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm using `lubridate` and I have a basic question. How can I choose all the values of a dataset that occur before a certain date?

For example, if I want to subset the values such that everything that occurs before July 8, what syntax do I use? I could not figure this out from reading the docs, or looking at the vignette example.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   1434 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ name      : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ value  : num  25 100 50 150 5 100 99 500 100 100 ...
 $ timestamp: POSIXct, format: "2014-06-27 10:49:20" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need `lubridate` I don't think. The following should work:

```
mydata[mydata$timestamp < as.POSIXct("2014-07-08"), ]
```

A version with `lubridate` would be similar:

```
mydata[mydata$timestamp < ymd("2014-07-08"), ]
```